# Jquery Fullcalender event displays twice in Week View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I have added a new event in fullcalender. The event is displayed as one div when displayed in "Day" view but it displayed as two attached divs when the view is changed to "Week".

[image]

Here is my script code:

```
@model Alis.AgentPortal.Models.MeetingVM
@using Alis.AgentPortal.Helpers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calender";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutforMarketRep.cshtml";
}
@section scripts{
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/Calender")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts")

}


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: false
        });

        function SetValidate() {
            var valMessage1 = "";
            if ($("#eventTitle").val() == "") {
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "Please enter subject.";
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "\n";
            }
            if ($("#eventDate").val() == "") {
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "Please enter effective date.";
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "\n";
            }
            //if ($("#Status").val() == "") {
            //    valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "Please enter Meeting Status.";
            //    valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "\n";
            //}
            var Req = $('#whoRequired').find(":selected").text();
            if (Req == null || Req == "") {
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "Please enter required person.";
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "\n";
            }
            var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
            if (!$('#eventDuration').val().match(numbers)) {
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "Please enter appointment length in numeric.";
                valMessage1 = valMessage1 + "\n";
            }

            return valMessage1;
        }

        $("#btnPopupSave").click(function () {

            if (SetValidate() != "") {
                alert(SetValidate());
            }
            else {
                $('#popupEventForm').hide();
                var blkstr = "";
                $.each($("#whoRequired").val(), function (idx2, val2) {
                    blkstr = val2 + "," + blkstr;
                });
                var Reminder = "";
                if ($('#chkReminder').prop('checked')) {
                    Reminder = true;
                } else {
                    Reminder = false;
                }
                var dataRow = {
                    'MeetingId': $('#MeetingId').val(),
                    'Title': $('#eventTitle').val(),
                    'NewEventTime': $('#eventTime').val(),
                    'WhoRequired': blkstr,
                    'Descripttion': $('#txtdescription').val(),
                    'Status': $('#Status').val(),
                    'NewEventDate': $('#eventDate').val(),
                    'Remider': Reminder,
                    'NewEventDuration': $('#eventDuration').val(),
                    'Notes': $('#txtnotes').val(),
                }

                ClearPopupFormValues();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/Calender/SaveEvent",
                    data: dataRow,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response == 'True') {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                            alert('New event saved!');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('Error, could not save event!');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        var sourceFullView = { url: '/Calender/GetDiaryEvents/' };
        var sourceSummaryView = { url: '/Calender/GetDiarySummary/' };
        var CalLoading = true;

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaDay',
            editable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotMinutes: 15,
            events: '/Calender/GetDiaryEvents/',
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                ShowEventDetails(calEvent.id);
                //alert(JSON.stringify(calEvent));
                //alert('You clicked on event id: ' + calEvent.id
                //    + "\nSpecial ID: " + calEvent.someKey
                //    + "\nAnd the title is: " + calEvent.title);
            },

            eventDrop: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
                if (confirm("Confirm move?")) {
                    UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start);
                }
                else {
                    revertFunc();
                }
            },

            eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) {

                if (confirm("Confirm change appointment length?")) {
                    UpdateEvent(event.id, event.start, event.end);
                }
                else {
                    revertFunc();
                }
            },

            dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                $('#eventTitle').val("");
                $('#eventDate').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'));
                $('#eventTime').val($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'HH:mm'));
                ShowEventPopup(date);
            },


            viewRender: function (view, element) {

                if (!CalLoading) {
                    if (view.name == 'month') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceSummaryView);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', sourceFullView);
                    }
                }

            }

        });

        CalLoading = false;

        $('#btnPopupCancel').click(function () {
            ClearPopupFormValues();
            $('#popupEventForm').hide();
        });

        $('#btnInit').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "/Calender/Init",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response == 'True') {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert('Database populated! ');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert('Error, could not populate database!');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });


    function ShowEventDetails(id) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Calender/GetDiaryEventsforBinding",
            data: { 'id': id },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != null) {


                    $("#MeetingId").val(data.collection[0].MeetingId);
                    $("#eventTitle").val(data.collection[0].MeetingSubject);
                    $("#eventDuration").val(data.collection[0].MeetingDuration);
                    $("#eventDate").val(formatDate(data.collection[0].ScheduledDate));
                    $("#eventTime").val(formatTime(data.collection[0].ScheduledDate));
                    var dataReq = data.collection[0].RequiredPersons;
                    var dataarray = dataReq.split(",");
                    $("#whoRequired").val(dataarray);
                    //$("#whoRequired").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                    var mstatus = data.collection[0].MeetingStatus;
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(abc))
                    //$("#Status").val(data.collection[0].MeetingStatus);

                    $("#Status option[value= '" + mstatus + "']").attr("selected", "selected");

                    if (data.collection[0].MeetingRemainder == "0") {
                        $("#chkReminder").prop('checked', false)
                    }
                    else { $("#chkReminder").prop('checked', true) }
                    $("#txtdescription").val(data.collection[0].MeetingDescription);
                    $("#txtnotes").val(data.collection[0].Notes);
                }
                else {
                    alert('Error, could not populate database!');
                }
            }
        });

        //$("#eventDate").val(data.collection.EventStart);
        //$("#eventDate").val(data.collection.EventStart);
        $('#popupEventForm').show();
    }

    function ShowEventPopup(date) {
        ClearPopupFormValues();
        $('#popupEventForm').show();
        $('#eventTitle').focus();
    }

    function ClearPopupFormValues() {
        $('#eventID').val('');
        $('#eventTitle').val('');
        $('#txtdescription').val('');
        $('#chkReminder').checked
        $('#eventDuration').val('');
        $('#txtNotes').val('');
        $('#whoRequired').val('');

    }

    function UpdateEvent(EventID, EventStart, EventEnd) {
        var dataRow = {
            'ID': EventID,
            'NewEventStart': EventStart,
            'NewEventEnd': EventEnd
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Calender/UpdateEvent",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(dataRow)

        });
    }
</script>

<link href="~/Content/Calender/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

I have tried my best but failed . Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in

`if (!CalLoading) {
                    if (view.name == 'month') { ....`

You catch the case that you change between month and week, and the case changing between month and day. But you don't catch the case of changing between day and week. In this last case you don't remove the `sourceFullView` that was loaded in this last scenario, and you load the same events one more time. That's why they are duplicated.

You should either create an `else if` scenario, or add `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceFullView);` 
in the `else` statement